# Vba save newly workbook with name in any user's system location

Tags: vba, excel

I want a new workbook creation that automatically saves at user's system but the path is not fixed so is there any way to do the same. I don't want that  User manually gives name ins ave as dialogue box. I want a macro that handles at runtime and saves the workbook in user's specific location.(Users are different)
Kindly suggest the code and approach for the same.
I have tried some variants:

```
Sub sb_Copy_Save_ActiveSheet_As_Workbook()
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Activate
wb.SaveAs "C:\temp\test3.xlsx"
End Sub
```

This gives me an error and I want the path that allows any user to save the file in their location without user's input(Save As Dialogue). Macro is able to save the file in any user's system.

Comment: "I want a macro"  - and a pony?  Typically here you're expected to show some effort toward solving your own problem first.

Comment: I have tried but that code is not relatable enough my code gives save as pop up and if you read my question carefully then I am also asking the approach

Comment: If you can't give suggestion then its ok but stop criticizing and also trying to understand the perspective of someone else  @Tim Williams

Comment: If you can't give suggestion then its ok but stop criticizing and also trying to understand the perspective of someone else @Shai Rado

Comment: @yashikavaish i wasn't critizing, Tim just made a funny comment with " - and a pony". To be straight to the point, it's impossible to help you without seeing your code, where are you struggeling, etc...

Comment: What *specific* part of your requirement is giving you problems?  We need a little bit more here than just a specification for some functionality...  How to get the users login on windows?  Answer right here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412418/how-can-i-display-my-windows-user-name-in-excel-spread-sheet-using-macros

Comment: You might also like to look at another question asked just 4 hours ago - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47665588/6535336 (currently 9th newest [excel-vba] question - so on the first page when sorted)

Comment: If you copy a worksheet to no destination, you end up with a new workbook with one worksheet (a copy of the original). Also lookup `environ` function to get user info.

Comment: Yes , I want file is being saved in any user's system in any location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy a worksheet to no destination, you end up with a new workbook with one worksheet (a copy of the original). Also lookup `environ` function to get user info.

```
activesheet.copy
activeworkbook.saveas filename:=environ("TEMP") & "\test", fileformat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
activeworkbook.close savechanges:=false
```