# Vba code to open file from a specific path that works for every user except temp

Tags: vba, excel

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Desktop\VBA\Phase 1\A.xlsx"
```

How do I open the file from desktop or documents of any user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47667406/4539709

Comment: Under desktop, There are subfolders with fixed names in which file is being kept so how to bypass those subfolders??

Comment: Are the subfolders same for all users?

Comment: Yes under desktop folders and subfolders names are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Multiple ways you can do that, pick the one that works for you-*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
                  .specialfolders("Desktop") & "\VBA\Phase 1\A.xlsx"
    Debug.Print FilePath
End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example2()
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\VBA\Phase 1\A.xlsx"
    Debug.Print FilePath
End Sub
```