# How to write a file path for two people mapped to different drives

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to write a code that saves a back up of an excel spreadsheet to the same shared folder, mapped to two different letters, only when certain users are saving. this is a file many people access, so I'd like to save a back up for only when myself or my coworker is in it.

I have the folder mapped to the G drive, my coworker has it on the I drive. How can I write the filepath to read both of our drives?

TIA!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Environ("Username") <> "agene" And Environ("Username") <> "aking" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SaveCopyAs ("\Excel\Backup\Backup of " & .Name)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Write the file directly to the UNC path (\\servername\folder\folder2\) - don't use the mapped drive letter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47667406/4539709

Comment: To find out the UNC path, as @TimWilliams writes, you can execute the `net use` command at a Windows command prompt.

Comment: Note - I'm not suggesting you don't map the drive at all, just to use the UNC path for cases where the drive letter is unknown

Answer (score 0):

Network paths are tricky. I created a function for my own library based on another author's work to determine the fully qualified path name to a network drive, given the drive letter. So take the drive letter for each user, determine the full network path, and always use that network path to save the file.

```
Public Function GetNetworkPath(ByVal driveName As String) As String
    '--- Converts a drive letter, e.g. 'W:\', to its fully qualified network
    '    path useful for saving a network folder location without any user-
    '    specific custom mapping
    '--- from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/
    '            658830-show-full-file-paths-unc-not-mapped-drive-letters-print.html
    Dim networkObject  As Object
    Dim networkDrives As Object

    Set networkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set networkDrives = networkObject.enumnetworkdrives

    Dim i As Long
    GetNetworkPath = vbNullString
    For i = 0 To networkDrives.count - 1 Step 2
        If UCase$(networkDrives.item(i)) = UCase$(driveName) Then
            GetNetworkPath = networkDrives.item(i + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```