# VBA to open file exported Excel file in PDF XChange Viewer

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Hi guys i'm brand new to coding but i have somehow (haha) managed to export my excel into `PDF`. Now Im having difficulties trying to have the PDF **automatically open** in **PDF XChange Viewer** instead of Adobe Reader.

Here are my codes:

```
Sub Export()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wsB As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveWorksheey

strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
wsa.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=myFile, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard,_
IncludeDocProperties:=True,_
IgnorePrintAreas:=False,_
OpenAfterPublish:=True

End If
End Sub
```

Disclaimer i copied the codes from somewhere online because i wanted to allow users to name the file, select where they save it.

What should i do to open the PDF in PDFXChange Viewer. The directory is: C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer

Comment: Always helps to show your existing code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694603/4539709

Comment: @PM. - this question is asking how to open the file in a specific application, not how to convert it. OP specified the file is already saved as `PDF`.  (The question was a little ambiguous but I clarified it on behalf of OP.)

Comment: misread the question @ashleedawg

Comment: 'twas an easy mistake @0m3r

Comment: apologies for the confusion!! included my codes alr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you already managed to export to PDF, so try below code to open the PDF file in `Adobe Reader` In case of `PDF XChange Viewer` put `XChange Viewer` exe file path in the code.

```
Sub OpenPDFbyAdobeReader()
    Dim exePath, filePath As String
    Dim OpenFile

    exePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
    filePath = "E:\CyberArk\DNA_Datasheet.pdf"
    openPath = exePath & " " & filePath

    OpenFile = Shell(openPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

## ***Edit***

Sub to save as pdf then open in a program.

```
Sub Export()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wsB As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim appPath As String
Dim OpenFile

    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    appPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

    strPath = wbA.Path
    If strPath = "" Then
        strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If
        strPath = strPath & "\"

        myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
        (FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

        If myFile <> "False" Then
            wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

            OpenFile = Shell(appPath & " " & myFile, vbNormalFocus)
        End If
End Sub
```

You have to replace `appPath` with your XChange viewer path.

Comment: could i ask for your help to see my codes and see how to include what you wrote? sorry i'm a beginner so i don't really understand :(

Comment: Can you please provide XChange viewer exe file path like I provided adobe reader path in my code. So, I will provide you full code to save and open the file in xchange viewer.

Comment: hi do u mean this: C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer

Comment: It should also have file name like `C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe`. Can you check it?

Comment: works now! thanks so much @harun24hr !!! another question: can i add textbox at a specific location in the pdf i have created?

Comment: If you found it working then accept (tick it as green) my answer so that other people can know it is useful answer. You can add textbox but I do not know much more about adding textbox. You can ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

### Open PDF in `PDFXCview`

Below is an example of how to call the application using `Shell`.  You'd need to specify the path/filename of your PDF, and you may need to confirm the location of `PDFXCview.exe` on your machine.

```
Sub OpenPDF_test()
    Const XCviewPath = "C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Editor\PDFXCview.exe"
    Const pdfFileName = "C:\myPath\myPDFfileName.pdf"
    Debug.Print XCviewPath & " """ & pdfFileName & """"
End Sub
```

---

### `PDFXCview.exe` Command Line Options

You can also add command line options if you want to automate more advanced tasks.

**For example**, you could have it:

- automatically print and then close the file,
- hide the user interface,
- import saved settings,
- or even ***run custom JavaScript***.

---

**Command Line switches**

```
/A "param=value [&param2=value [&...]"
/close[:save|discard|ask]
/print[:[default=yes|no][&showui=yes|no][&printer=<printername>][&pages=<pagesrange>]]
/printto[:[default=yes|no][&showui=yes|no][&pages=<pagesrange>]] <printername>
/exportp <setting_file_name>
/importp <setting_file_name>
/RegServer
/UnregServer
/usep <setting_file_name>
```

### **More Information [Here](https://help.tracker-software.com/EUM/default.aspx?pageid=PDFXView25:command_line_options).**